# R survey package function svyciprop with "likelihood" method

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to calculate confidence intervals of proportions using the R survey package function svyciprop with the "likelihood" method.

Here's some sample code:

```
df <- data.frame(id =  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), var = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"))
survey_design <- svydesign(id = ~id, data = df)
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood")
```

This generates the error message:

```
Error in seq.int(xmin, xmax, length.out = n) : 'from' must be finite
```

I can find nothing in the package documentation that explains how to get this to work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation for `svyciprop` is found by typing `?svyciprop` or by googling `svyciprop` but the documentation won't cover something as specific as your error.

since all R code is available for users to read, you can debug the function that you are using.  debug `survey:::svyciprop` which leads you to `survey:::confint.svyglm` which leads you to `MASS:::confint.glm` which leads you to `MASS:::confint.profile.glm` and so on.  the internet has lots of explanations of how to use the `debug` function in R.  there are a lot of moving parts here

you're getting some `Inf` values from the glm objects deep in this calculation that's causing it to break.  it's probably related to your example data set being a bit too perfect (and unrealistic).  ;)

if i throw out a single observation from your `df` then it works.

```
library(survey)
df <- data.frame(id =  c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), var = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b"))
survey_design <- svydesign(id = ~id, data = df)
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood")
```

the example data sets found at the bottom of `?svyciprop` also work.

your particular issue is that the confidence interval you're requesting is impossible.

```
# watch how the confidence interval tends toward zero and one as you widen it.
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood",level=0.8)
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood",level=0.9)
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood",level=0.93)
svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood",level=0.95) # this is the default
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your outstanding website on analyzing survey data and using the R survey package. It has been invaluable to our team. Thanks also for your reply to this question. Your tips into debugging and reading R code are very helpful. We have a number of real survey datasets for which `svyciprop` works with the `"logit"` and `"beta"` methods, but it doesn't work with the `"likelihood"` method on any of them, giving the above error message. Is there any additional documentation on using `svyciprop` with the `"likelihood"` method?

Comment: documentation doesn't always cover extreme use cases like yours, you really need to `debug` things on your own ;)  i've added to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for finding the solution to this problem. I suspect it will help others who encounter the same problem of trying to use `svyciprop` with the `"likelihood"` method and the default level. With our datasets, the level where it first works is 0.74.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in this example is that the denominator degrees of freedom are too small. The code in the survey package ends up calling `MASS::confint.glm` to get the interval, but the interval half-width is about 10 (compared to, say, 1.96 for iid sampling and large samples).  That means a nominal one-sided tail probability of 1.6e-25 has to be given to `MASS::confint.glm`. Unfortunately, `MASS::confint.glm` wants this in the form 1-1.6e-25, which is 1 up to machine precision.

You can specify the denominator degrees of freedom using the `df` argument: with these data you get a result down to `df=2`.

```
> svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "like",df=5)
                     2.5% 97.5%
I(var == "a") 0.500 0.117  0.88
> svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "like",df=4)
                      2.5% 97.5%
I(var == "a") 0.5000 0.0993   0.9
> svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "like",df=3)
                       2.5% 97.5%
I(var == "a") 0.5000 0.0696  0.93
> svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "like",df=2)
                       2.5% 97.5%
I(var == "a") 0.5000 0.0216  0.98
> svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "like",df=1)
Error in seq.int(xmin, xmax, length.out = n) : 'from' must be finite
```

It's pretty clear that the confidence interval will stretch from nearly 0 to nearly 1

Answer (score 2):

The error is fixed in version 3.31-4. However, the interval is still reported as

```
 > svyciprop(~I(var == "a"), survey_design, method = "likelihood",level=0.95)
                   2.5% 97.5%
 I(var == "a") 0.5  0.0    NA
```

As Anthony indicates, the problem is that the true confidence interval goes from nearly 0 to nearly 1.